# How to Access Object values in server side

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:attribute name="objDetail" type="GSS_User_Skill__c" default="{'sobjectType' : 'GSS_User_Skill__c'}" access="global"/>
```

Js side:

```
   var action =component.get("c.InsertUserSkills");
    alert('call--->'+JSON.stringify(component.get("v.objDetail")));
    action.setParams({
        "UserSkills":component.get("v.objDetail")
 });
```

In server side recieving value like this:

```
  @AuraEnabled
public static List<GSS_User_Skill__c> InsertUserSkills(sObject UserSkills){
  system.debug('Insert UserSkills---->'+UserSkills);}
```

Debug Log:

```
Insert UserSkills---->GSS_User_Skill__c:{Parameter__c=Severity, ValueText__c=1, ValuePick__c=1 - Critical, Level__c=1}
```

How can I access GSS_User_Skill__c values, If I access like this

```
         UserSkills.Parameter__c;
```

it shows Parameter__c undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a variable as an untyped `sObject`:

```
sObject UserSkills
```

you only get to access the fields and methods that are defined for `sObject` itself - such as the core `get()` and `put()` methods, and the `Id` field. Like with any other type in Apex, you cannot access member fields that don't exist on that type.

Declare, or cast, the correct type - `GSS_User_Skill__c` - and the compiler will allow you to access fields like `Parameter__c`. Alternately, you can use `sObject`'s `get()` method, but it returns an `Object`, so you'll have to do a lot of casting.